# Exception during elaborating the image: OpenCV

Tags: java, c++, opencv, image-processing

I am new at OpenCV and I don't know why does this exception occur.

```
if (!frame.empty())
{
    List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<>();
    Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
    // convert the image to gray scale
    Mat dilateElement = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new Size(24,24));
    Mat erodeElement = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new Size(12,12));
    Imgproc.cvtColor(frame, gray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    Imgproc.threshold(gray, gray,128, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);
    Imgproc.blur(gray, gray, new Size(7,7));
    Imgproc.erode(gray, gray, erodeElement);
    Imgproc.dilate(gray, gray, dilateElement);                                  
    Imgproc.findContours(gray, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
    while(contours != null)
    {
        MatOfPoint thisContour = new MatOfPoint();
        for (int idx = 0; idx >= 0; idx = (int) hierarchy.get(0, idx)[0]
        {
            MatOfPoint2f thisContour2f = new MatOfPoint2f();
            MatOfPoint approxContour = new MatOfPoint();
            MatOfPoint2f approxContour2f = new MatOfPoint2f();
            thisContour.convertTo(thisContour2f, CvType.CV_32FC2);
            Imgproc.approxPolyDP(thisContour2f,approxContour2f,0.02,true);
            approxContour2f.convertTo(approxContour, CvType.CV_32S);
            if(approxContour.size().height==4)
            {
                Rect ret = Imgproc.boundingRect(approxContour);
                text_field.setText("nice");
            }
```

I have converted the code from c++. And that is the error.

```
    OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (npoints >= 0 && (depth == CV_32S || depth == CV_32F)) in cv::approxPolyDP, file C:\builds\master_PackSlaveAddon-win32-vc12-static\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\approx.cpp, line 679 Exception during the image elaboration: CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: C:\builds\master_PackSlaveAddon-win32-vc12-static\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\approx.cpp:679: error: (-215) npoints >= 0 && (depth == CV_32S || depth == CV_32F) in function cv::approxPolyDP]
```

I've tried everything to fix it but unsuccessfully.

Comment: are you reading the contours at all in your loop?!?

Comment: MatOfPoint thisContour = new MatOfPoint(); shouldnt this be sth like MatOfPoint thisContour = contours[idx]?? sorry I dont know the Java API...

Comment: thanks, that was the problem... but another one occured

Comment: Exception during the image elaboration: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0